# Python3 Sorted function not behaving as expected, getting different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lexicographic

Why is this weird behaviour:

```
a  = ['This','is','some','banana']
"_".join(sorted(a)).
```

Output -

> This_is_banana_some

It should give the output -

> is_banana_some_this

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would `T` be between `i` and `t`? `T` is 84 and `i` is 105, so `This` should be before `is`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the sorting key - lowercase `str` in your case.

```
"_".join(sorted(a, key=str.lower))
```

This works. By default python places uppercase first.